# Can you tell me logback.xml a full template?

Tags: logging, logback

I can't find  logback.xml full template in logback site,Can you tell me  a full template example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Google codesearch](http://code.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=logback.xml) or some [examples](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/tree/master/logback-examples/src/main/java/chapters).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Logback Configuration Wizard](http://wizardforge.org/pc?action=displayFlowchartVersionPublic&id=42) created by Dirk Ooms to generate Logback configuration files.

Comment: Awesome awesome awesome!!! Sure beats reading 500 pages about the LogManagerContextOutputWtfBbq class...

Comment: That utility has seized to be, it is an ex-wizard: "WizardForge was an interesting adventure, but it became time to discontinue it. The wizards for log4j and logback are added as examples at wizard4j"